# Group objects by multiple attributes with Java 8 stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given we have a list of Bank, each Bank have multiple offices,

```
public class Bank {
   private String name;
   private List<String> branches;
   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }
   public List<String> getBranches(){
       return branches;
   }
}
```

For example:

```
Bank "Mizuho": branches=["London", "New York"]
Bank "Goldman": branches = ["London", "Toronto"]
```

Given a list of banks, I would have a map of bank representation for each city. In the example above, I need a result of

```
Map["London"] == ["Mizuho", "Goldman"]
Map["New York"] == ["Mizuho"]
Map["Toronto"] == ["Goldman"]
```

How can I achieve that result using Java 8 API? Using pre-Java8 is easy, but verbose. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<String, Set<Bank>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Bank bank : banks) {
    for (String branch : bank.getBranches()) {
        result.computeIfAbsent(branch, b -> new HashSet<Bank>()).add(bank);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 banks.flatMap(bank -> bank.getBranches()
             .stream()
             .map(branch -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(branch, bank)))
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             Entry::getKey, 
             Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Result would be:

```
{London=[Mizuho, Goldman], NewYork=[Mizuho], Toronto=[Goldman]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the version of [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) that accepts a supplier, an accumulator function and a combiner function, as follows:

```
Map<String, List<Bank>> result = banks.stream()
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (map, bank) -> bank.getBranches().forEach(branch ->
            map.computeIfAbsent(branch, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(bank)),
        (map1, map2) -> map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, (l1, l2) -> {
            l1.addAll(l2);
            return l1;
        })));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think solution provided by @JB Nizet is one of the most simple/efficient solutions. it can also be rewritten by forEach

```
banks.forEach(b -> b.getBranches().forEach(ch -> result.computeIfAbsent(ch, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(b)));
```

Another short solution by Stream with [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Map<String, List<Bank>> res = Stream.of(banks)
          .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getBranches()).map(b -> Pair.of(b, e)))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap2());
```